# Typescript class as parameter or prototype of superclass

Tags: typescript, class, inheritance, prototype, superclass

I try to create a master class referencing a prototype class (service) from which will derive 2 sub-classes (A1 and A2) each using 2 specific services (S1 and S2).

Still a novice in <del>Javascript</del> TypeScript development and I can't find what I need on SO...

```
    class MasterClass<T> {
        public f1(){
                new T().hi();
        }
    }

    class S1 {
        public hi() {
            console.log("Hi from S1");
        }
    }

    class S2 {
        public hi() {
            console.log("Hi from S2");
        }
    }

    class A1 extends MasterClass<S1> {
        constructor() {
            f1();
        }
    }

    class A2 extends MasterClass<S2> {
        constructor() {
            f1();
        }
    }

    new A1();
    new A2();
```

So far, here is what I've tried with no result :-(

The expected result here would be:

```
Hi from S1
Hi from S2
```

Comment: read [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_class_inheritance.asp)

Comment: First: `<T>` is a generic argument but only in TypeScript. JS does not have generics. Second, in TS the generics will be type erased. You cannot have `func<T>() { new T() }` as `T` does not exist at runtime. There is no way to refer to the generic at that point. You need a concrete thing to use.

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen Already have read this article but it's too generic and far from my problem

Comment: As VLAZ explained you can't use TypeScript types as a basis for runtime logic. You should rather work to understand the Class system (as described in the linked article above or more fully on [MDN: Class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)). Here's a quick [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xc2ke5r3/)

Comment: @VLAZ It's actually a typescript question. Just thought this existed in JS. Is there a way in TS to do such a thing ?

Comment: @BartmanDilaw No, not with generics only. You need a concrete item in order to call `new` on it, which means you need to pass a constructor.

Comment: ```class MasterClass<T> {
       constructor(private readonly class: T)
        public f1(){
                new this.T.hi();
        }
    }```  you can try to make a generic class as you did, but also provide the class (or instance of the class) in constructor and use it inside other methods. As @VLAZ stated, generics are just typescript construct for helping with defining the code, they are not existing in real world - just in the sourcecode. So you cannot use them in other way as editor helpers.

Comment: @pilchard thanks for the fiddle... I'll try that !

Comment: @VLAZ pilchard fiddle will surely help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The TypeScript generics [cannot be used at runtime to instantiate new object](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-cant-i-write-typeof-t-new-t-or-instanceof-t-in-my-generic-function). They are only available at compiletime to ensure you are working with the correct types but after that they are erased and the JavaScript code has no knowledge nor ability to find out what the the generic argument is.

Furthermore, even if it could, there is no way to ensure it is callable with `new` (is it a constructor) or callable at all. For example, if we take `new MasterClass<string>()` then there is no way to make `new T` out of it, since strings are a primitive. And if the constructor is supposed to take any parameters, then it also not work.

Instead what you need is a concrete object to work with. Which you can also describe in the typings in order to make sure everything is correct.

```typescript
interface Greetable {
  hi: () => void;
}

class MasterClass<T extends Greetable> {
  constructor(private ctor: new () => T) { }
  public f1() {
    new this.ctor().hi();
  }
}

class S1 {
  public hi() {
    console.log("Hi from S1");
  }
}

class S2 {
  public hi() {
    console.log("Hi from S2");
  }
}

class A1 extends MasterClass<S1> {
  constructor() {
    super(S1);
    this.f1();
  }
}

class A2 extends MasterClass<S2> {
  constructor() {
    super(S2);
    this.f1();
  }
}

new A1();
new A2();
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOJQhMcBGAbFAbwFgAoZZAC2AC5kAKASmQF4A+ZANwHtgATANxkAvmTII8cAM5TkAWWmQoAYUkyAPABVkEAB6QQfWekzZ8EDiXLIE3EFLBQArgjDco9AA5RgnOJBs3KDoQCAB3BmZ2ZE1mQmRRa08nfGAEZBgARiZkKwoKUIiwaikAOld3JlLqJiFrRMTxNVkAZUzcsgpk1PSauM7823tuAlK8bgBzegAiAAlgDKhuAFtkNunGOooGsVIJaVaAJg6klLw0qmAcvMG7KRGIMcmZ+cWVtcONrYSRXf2ZZAAQXaegMRnkimgqgO6jalgGQwczgqHn61goUicnmg9DamwGFGKwDKWVqAx2pCaByBx1BEEMsgUDihzVhh3h1kRjhcQWuBOQmOxHhah3x6OQRJJ2TF21+lNIhSB0rqisBh1qQA)

Here are the important differences:

1. `MasterClass` uses [a constrained generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints). It *has* to be assignable to something with a `hi` method.
2. The constructor of `MasterClass` accepts [a class type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#using-class-types-in-generics). It needs a constructor for `T` to be passed in. With it, `new this.ctor` can be used instead of `new T` because `this.ctor` is now a concrete object that exists at runtime and can be called.
3. `A1` and `A2` need to pass an appropriate constructor in order to be instantiated properly. Which now satisfies the `MasterClass` constructor and its generic constraint.